# Using jScrollPane, drag block doesn't go to the bottom of scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I've used jScrollPane before but I'm having some trouble getting it right this time.

I am using it in two pages of the site, and on both the drag block (orange box, in my case) never reaches the bottom of the scroll track. I've tried a number of things playing with margins and padding but can't seem to get it to respond.

I'll keep code out of the post solely because it's probably easier to just Firebug the thing, but please comment if you need more information.

The two pages it occurs on are http://juisebox.com/fmg/index.php/work-with-us/contracts and http://juisebox.com/fmg/index.php/news-and-media/publications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of jscrollpanedrage is not set properly.

Reduce the height of that , it is scrolling till botton.
through firebug i made it 20px, it could scroll to the bottom.

The way you set the div has some problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had the height of that div set to 16px, which is correct, but the plugin was generating incorrect inline CSS which overrode my style. I set the 16px to !important in my CSS and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the behaviour of jScrollPane is correct and expected when it sets the height of the drag. This is because as with native scrollbars the height of the drag is proportional to the amount of content that needs to be scrolled.

If you want to fix the height of the drag and override this behaviour then use the dragMinHeight and dragMaxHeight setting properties (set them both to 16px in your example) if you are using jScrollPane version 1. If you are using version 2 (recommended) then please see this example:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/drag_size.html